# the navigation bar disappears when i switch between view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

ok so i have no errors in my code according to Xcode. I have switched between views programmatically because i want to link the page switch to the results of a uialertview but whenever i switch the view it switches fine then when i return to the main screen the navigation bar disappears.

to switch the views i am using

```
InfoViewController *infoView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"infoView"];
[self presentViewController:infoView animated:NO completion:NULL];
```

and then the same code to return back but changing the identifier.

Comment: `then the same code to return back but changing the identifier.` What do you mean by that? You are presenting a view modally and then doing it again to return to the main view?

Answer (score 0):

Use pop to move back to previous screen.Now you are creating a new instance and push it again[You said using the same code to move back]

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try segues

```
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueName" sender: self];
```

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/) is the tutorial for that.